# mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a Centos server with apache and PHP on it, and I have a SQL Server on another server, when I try to connect to `MSSQL` with `tsql -H` "sql server ip" `-p1433 -U sa`, it works and  connects OK, but when I try to run following `PHP` code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$connection = mssql_connect('serverIP', 'username', 'password');
```

I get the error :

> Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: serverIP in
>   /var/www/html/mssql.php on line 4

what should I do?

Comment: echo mssql_get_last_message() to get the specific error

Comment: I did that and it shows blank!!

Comment: It seems there could be issues with your login info

Comment: no, my username and password works ok when I try to connect with tsql -H  !!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the servername and the instance like in this example,I think:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

EDIT:
The following method: server\instance
does'nt work on unix systems...

An instance is nothing more than specific port address different than 1433... so just discover the port on mssql server and then try to connect using:

ip:port

In unix the port is specified by : not by ,

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I noticed that I coulnd't connect when I was giving the DB server name, but when I gave the IP adress directly, it worked !

Maybe this information could be helpful to others...

**Edit :** after some research, I think this can be related to the freetds.conf file, which may contain server definitions. When using a name instead of an IP, I'm pretty sure that the driver is looking for a TDS definition of the same name...